# How to update ListView when QR code is detected?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to show items in ListView which have exact name as QR code. I'm using ZXing and list is showed from deserializing JSON file on website. Mine code which handles QR code result is:

```
public void Handle_OnScanResult(Result result)
{

    string wynik = result.Text;
    ItemPage P = new ItemPage();
    Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    P.Receive_result(wynik);

}
```

It's taking result.Text as **wynik**, closes window with camera and sends it to this code:

```
public void Receive_result(string wynik)
{
    ItemsListView.ItemsSource = itemlist.Where(x => x.Nazwa.Equals(wynik));
}
```

When it reads QR code, value is stored and sended to Receive_result, but it's not updating the list.
Theres whole code which is responsible to show ListView and deserialize object:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Diabetics.Models;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace Diabetics.Views
{
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class ItemPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> itemlist = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        public ItemPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadAll();

            ItemsListView.RefreshCommand = new Command(() => {
                LoadAll();
                ItemsListView.IsRefreshing = false;
            });

        }
//code to receive value wynik and update list
        public void Receive_result(string wynik)
        {
                ItemsListView.ItemsSource = itemlist.Where(x => x.Nazwa.Equals(wynik));

        }
//searchbar
        public void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.NewTextValue))
            {
                ItemsListView.ItemsSource = itemlist;
            }
            else
            {
                ItemsListView.ItemsSource = itemlist.Where(x => x.Nazwa.Contains(e.NewTextValue));
            }
        }
//On click to show item details
        async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (!(args.SelectedItem is Item item))
                return;

            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ItemDetailPage(item.Nazwa, item.Opis, item.Zdjecie, item.WW, item.WBT, item.Energia, item.Tluszcz, item.Weglowodany, item.Blonnik, item.Bialko, item.Zelazo, item.Wapn, item.Code));

            ItemsListView.SelectedItem = null;
        }
//Button to show camera
        private async void ToolbarItem_ClickedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new FullScreenScanning());
        }

//Json Deserialization
        public async void LoadAll()
        {
            waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
            waitActivityIndicator.IsVisible = true;
            string result = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                HttpClient Klient = new HttpClient();
                Klient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://next.json-generator.com");
                string url = string.Format("/api/json/get/4yvwrz2bd");
                var response = await Klient.GetAsync(url);
                result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", string.Format("Musisz być podłączony do internetu", ex.Message), "OK");
                waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
                waitActivityIndicator.IsVisible = false;
            }
            waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
            waitActivityIndicator.IsVisible = false;
            itemlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Item>>(result);
            ItemsListView.ItemsSource = itemlist;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: have you debugged `Receive_result` to verify that it is receiving the data and that the LINQ query is actually returning a result?  Have you tried executing the code on the UI thread?

Comment: @Jason it's receiving data, but as I see LINQ query doesn't return anything, and how i can execute it on UI thread?

Comment: If the query isn’t working then that’s your problem.  Fix that first

Comment: itemlist count=0 but "wynik" have exact value as QR code and one item in listview

it looks like this https://imgur.com/a/HDquxr3

Comment: how is your scan page calling `Receive_result`?  You don't appear to be passing a reference to the page when you call `FullScreenScanning`

Comment: First code on thread, im just passing wynik string

Comment: you are creating a new instance of the page.  That is NOT the same instance of the page that is already in the navigation stack.  You either need to pass a reference to ItemPage when you call the scan page, OR use MessagingCenter to pass a message between the pages

Comment: How I can pass that reference? I was searching over the internet and that's only what I found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) would be the idea way to do this, but you could also pass a reference to the parent page

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new FullScreenScanning(this));
```

in the constructor, store the reference

```
ItemPage Parent;

public FullScreenScanning(ItemsPage parent)
{
  this.Parent = parent;
}
```

then

```
public void Handle_OnScanResult(Result result)
{
   string wynik = result.Text;
   Parent.Receive_result(wynik);
   Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
}
```

Comment: I did it and it says that parent doesn't exist in current context https://imgur.com/a/6UE7BmZ

Comment: did you name it "Parent" or "parent"?

Comment: I tried with "Parent" and it doesn't even close FullScreenScanning, its just informing me on Debug window that BarcodeFound

Comment: I can't hold your hand through every step of debugging.  Is it executing the Pop?  Is ItemsPage receiving the code?  Perhaps try calling Pop first, then Receive_result.

Comment: Im so sorry. I had it before Receive_result before and i thought it was wrong. Thanks it works but i need to tap somewhere on screen to refresh it, theres way to show this item automatically?

Comment: It shows only this one item until i restart the application, even pull to refresh doesnt change that. Okay i will look at it

Comment: This sounds like a different problem.  Debug it.